# getting different values when encrypting and decrypting values in crypto-js

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am trying to make an authentication system for an online store, and to do this I am encrypting passwords with crypto-js. When testing my authentication script I realized that when I encrypt a password and then decrypt it I get a different result.

```
//Register
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
      req.body.password,
      process.env.PASS_SEC
    ).toString(),
  });
  try {
    const savedUser = await newUser.save({ w: 1 });
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//Login
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    !user && res.status(401).json("Incorrect Username");
    const password = await CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      user.password,
      process.env.PASS_SEC
    ).toString();
    console.log(password);
    if (password !== req.body.password) {
      res.status(401).json("Incorrect Password");
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(user);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

my code is listed above. I can't seem to figure out what is going on.

for example if I encrypt 123456789, when decrypted I will get 313233343536373839.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing encrypted passwords. Instead you should be storing password hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking into the issue I found that the error was related to converting the hashed password to a string. Giving `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8` to `toString()` as a parameter fixes the issue.